# Prove there exists a subsequence of the real numbers such that it is monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Prove that there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that either $x_{n_{k+1}} \le x_{n_k} $ for all $k$ or $x_{n_{k+1}} \ge x_{n_k} $ for all $k$.

Would it suffice to define $\{a_p\}$ as $a_p = x_{n_k}$, $n_k = min\{n \ |\ x_n \gt x_{n_{k-1}}\}$ and $\{b_p\}$ as $b_p = x_{n_k}$, $n_k = min\{n \ |\ x_n \lt x_{n_{k-1}}\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is essentially the idea. If there are infinitely many indices $n$ with the property that $m > n$ implies $x_n > x_m$, enumerate these indices by $n_k$ to conclude that $x_{n_1} > x_{n_2} > x_{n-3} > \cdots$  Otherwise there is a largest such index (or possibly none at all). Thus there is a point $n_1$ in the sequence with the property that for every $n \ge n_1$ there exists $m > n$ with $x_n \le x_m$. You can thus find $n_k$ so that  $x_{n_1} \le x_{n_2} \le x_{n_3} \le \cdots$